# How to get publisher Certificate Name for a given Nuget package from a nuget server

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I need to get if a given list of packages hosted on a nuget server (ex: nuget.org) is signed by the publisher and if it is I need to have the name. This information is available on nuget package explorer view as follows (I only want the info in the red box):
[image]

Currently I have a console app using nuget client SDK and can query with following code (foreach not shown):

```
resource = await repository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>()
resource.GetMetadataAsync(packageName, true, false, cache, logger, cancellationToken);
```

However returned object does not have this property and couldnt find any methods in the SDK that returns this information. I am hoping to get this information without downloading the package.

Comment: The docs for NuGet's network protocol is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview.  There's nothing for signed package certificate information, so it's not possible without downloading the package.